# C# Compare two Lists

Tags: c#, excel, list

**Background:** I have two lists that hold strings. List a and List b. At the moment I write the values of List a in an excel spreadsheet to column A, and the values of List b into Column. List b should have the same data as List a and be in sequence. This is not always the case.

**Problem:** When I write values of List b in excel, I want to write the value in the cell if it is in list a at the same point, if not I want to write an empty string into the cell.

Edit:
Thanks for replies and answers work very well, just realised that what I really need is :

If two lists are:

```
a = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }
b = {"a", "d", "e" }
```

the result of the operation should be:

```
{ "a", "", "", "d", "e" }
```

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @X.L.Ant Lots, at the moment i am using the except method to get what it does not have.

Comment: pseudo code: if List2[current index] == List1[current index] then write List2[current index] else write String.Empty;

Comment: If the lists contain item pairs (item_i of list a is connected to item_i of list b), why don't you create your own datatype that saves both items as properties instead of 2 separate lists?

Comment: How do you even know, a value in listB is in any way "connected" to a value in listA? By its position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to [`zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) your lists together and replace the "wrong" value in list b with an empty string:

```
var a = new [] {"a",   "b", "c",   "d"};
var b = new [] {"a", "Foo", "c", "Bar"};

var fixed_b = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x == y ? x : "");
```

`fixed_b` now yields `"a"`, `""`, `"c"` and `""`.

When writing your data to your excel spreadsheet, simply iterate over `fixed_b` instead of `b`

**Edit:**

According to your comments:

You could create a little helper method like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> FillBlanks<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> collection, T blank)
{
    using(var e = collection.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool more = e.MoveNext();
        foreach(var x in source)
            if(more && x.Equals((T)e.Current))
            {
                yield return x;
                more = e.MoveNext();
            }
            else
                yield return blank;
    }
}

var fixed_b = FillBlanks(a, b, String.Empty);
```

Comment: Another way would be to use `zip` to iterate over `a` and `b` "simultaneously", like `foreach(var t in a.Zip(b, Tuple.Create))`. `t` is now a `Tuple`, and the `Item1` property contains the a-values, while the `Item2` property contains the b-values. Then you could easily compare them, like `if (t.Item1 != t.Item2)`.

Comment: Hi Dominico works well but i ran into a problem. If two lists are a = {"a","b","c", "d", "e" } , and b = {"a", "d", "e" } . I need fixed_b to yield { "a", "", "", "d", "e" }

Comment: @luckyluke No problem, but you have to use a little helper method. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
int max = aList.Count > bList.Count ? aList.Count : bList.Count;
for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    if(i < aList.Count)
        Write(aList[i]);

    if(i < bList.Count)
    {
        if(i < aList.Count)
            Write(aList[i] == bList[i] ? bList[i] : "");
        else
            Write(bList[i]);
    }
}
```

This assumes `Write` actually writes data to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
        List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "b" };

        var result = listB.Select((b, index) =>
            (index == listA.IndexOf(b)) ? b : "");
    }
}
```